# Android Reading/parsing data from JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I am  getting the following JSON object:

```
{
  "12.9624669, 77.6381958": "Domlur, Bangalore, Bangalore Urban, Karnataka, India",
  "12.9612856, 77.6362465": "Domlur, Old Airport Road, Domlur, Bangalore, Bangalore Urban, Karnataka, 560071, India",
  "12.9614031, 77.636241": "Domlur, HAL Airport Road, Domlur, Bangalore, Bangalore Urban, Karnataka, 560071, India"
}
```

I want to retrieve the data from this object and store it in an array.

I would like to retrieve only part of the data, ie. only "Domlur, Old Airport Road" or "Domlur , HAL Airport Road", and not the whole string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json.trim());
    Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String s = jObject.getString((String) keys.next());
        s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(",", s.indexOf(",") + 1));
        result.add(s);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate across JSON keys and with dynamic values and its contents like this:

```
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr); //jsonStr is your JSON
            Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();                     
            while (iter.hasNext()) { 
                String key = iter.next();  //gets the dynamic key
                Log.v("printlog","Dynamic Gps key: "+key);
                try { 
                    String content=json.getString(key); // gets contents from the dynamic key
                    Log.v("printlog","Content: "+content);

                }catch (JSONException e) { }
```